# Database with HTTP API out of the box

Tags: database, rest, http

I am looking for a database with HTTP REST API out of the box. I want to skip the middle tier between client and database.

One option I found is a HTTP Plugin for MySQL which operates with JSON format
http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2014/mysql-5-7-http-plugin-mysql/

Can someone suggest other similar solutions? I want to save development time and effort for some queries.

Comment: You're asking for outside resources (i.e., "other similar solutions"), which is off topic for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should have a middle layer to sanitize input and prevent unwanted calls deleting or changing your data, IMO.

Since you claim to just be testing, though, the technologies I know off the top of my head that provide REST out of the box are mostly NoSQL. You mention MySQL with that JSON thing, but I imagine that just goes through a JDBC/ODBC layer.

So what I know is:

Solr/Elasticsearch - while not strictly a database, is useful for quickly searchable semi structured data

Couchbase - a distributed document and key value store for JSON documents

Neo4j - Graph database

Comment: @Drew - True, but it stores JSON documents just like Mongo. Elastic may not have the same query capabilities, put for simple document retrieval and insertion, it works. Plus search can be useful in some instances

Comment: Thank you! My idea was to launch a working application quickly so the sales guys can do their demos and later secure the backend. These should be enough for now and I will decide if I want to go on with some of these options.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Database offers 'HTTP,' out-of-the-box, but it is via a mid-tier. The technology is known as [Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS)](https://oracle.com/rest)

It *could* be hosted on the same server as your database if you wanted to avoid setting up a separate server. Note, that's not generally recommended.

This technology gives you the following for your Oracle Database:

- PL/SQL Gateway, invoke stored procedures via https, get database generated web content back
- REST APIs for your Oracle Database
- SQL Developer Web, a web application front-end to your database
- JSON/Mongo, interact with your database via JSON object/document calls, with MongoDB API support

This is included with your database, no additional cost, and it's also supported along with your database.

If you're in the Oracle Cloud, our Autonomous Database services have this pre-configured and running from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can you firebase or supabase to achieve what you want.